# Scala Akka Actors act() function

Tags: scala, akka

All the tutorials that I have read work like this:

```
class HelloWorldActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case "Hello" => self.reply("World")
  }
}

val myActor = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor], name = "myactor")
```

I am wondering if AKKA supports the act() function inside an Actor class like this:

```
class HelloWorldActor extends Actor {
  def act() = {

  }
}
```

And then you can call:

```
val myActor = new HelloWorldActor
myActor.start()
```

I want to do this because my actor won't be receieving any messages. It just works on its own. So can I use the act() function inside my AKKA actor?

Comment: What does your actor react on then, if it is not receiving any messages? Maybe all you need is a [Future](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/futures.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Akka, your actor should start automatically after creation using the system. But it sounds as if you want to use the actor like a plain thread we all know from Java. I would say that this is not the right way from an idiomatic point of view. You can of course just add a start message to your actor, send it to the actor after creation, and do your processing in the handler. But perhaps you should consider using a plain thread or a Future instead of an actor if you do not want to react on any message?

Comment: How do I use a plain thread or a future? Are futures functions? I am not clear on how to use a future after reading the tutorial.

Comment: For a plain thread, just extend the Java Thread class and implement the `run()` method. There are many examples out there. For a Future, @Debilski already linked you to an article explaining its use. Have a look at the "Use Directly" section. If both solutions do not fit your problem, you should describe it in more detail.